# Emacs font style and colorisation

Tags: microsoft-windows, fonts, syntax-highlighting, colors, ubuntu

I am used to Emacs under Windows 10 and trying to switch to Ubuntu.

My Windows 10 Emacs font is M-x describe-font:

```
    name (opened by): -outline-Courier New-normal-normal-normal-mono-13-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1
       full name: Courier New-10.0
            size: 13
          height: 16
 baseline-offset:  0
relative-compose:  0
  default-ascent: 12
          ascent: 12
         descent:  4
   average-width:  8
     space-width:  8
       max-width: 10
```

And the result is: [image]

The default Emacs font in Ubuntu is more beautiful but less readable for me (I have astigmatism):
[image]

So to find the same font as in Windows, I use this setting in `.emacs` file:

```
(set-face-font 'default "-Mono-Courier New-normal-normal-normal-*-14-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")
```

I like the font which is for me more easy to read but colours contrasts are too low. Why?
[image]

For colours I use:

```
(set-foreground-color "wheat")
(set-background-color "#273149")
(set-cursor-color "white")
```

And web-mode: http://web-mode.org/

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

How to find the same font style and colourisation I am used to on Windows?

Comment: To me the colors look ok, but in your Ubuntu screenshot, they don't "pop" like your Windows screenshot. Instead of mucking about with Emacs's colors, try changing the gamma and brightness of the Xorg server. (I assume you're using the same monitor for Windows and Ubunutu, so hardware settings are out.) You can do this via a terminal and with the `xrandr` utility. See this [SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97721/how-to-change-the-xorg-gamma-brightness) for examples and a gotcha.

Comment: @nega Strange but if I choose the bold version of Courier New, the colours "pop" better and are more readable with these "popped" colours but I don't like the bold version. `(set-face-font 'default "-Mono-Courier New-bold-normal-normal-*-14-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1")`: https://i.imgur.com/iPUdRRS.png Maybe I am too used to Windows fonts and should get used to Ubuntu/Linux ones!

Comment: My best guess is that this is a difference between Linux and windows don’t rendering. Maybe you can change font-config to make hinting more aggressive to help with this.